# Only show specific values in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
text = 'hello'
vowels = 'aeiou'
```

how do I make it so that it prints something like , "the vowel a occurs x times"

Comment: Find the smallest value and then print the entries that match.

Comment: Then you don't need to preload the dict with those defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a slightly different approach and only instantiate dictionary keys for vowels that exist in the string.

```
text = 'hello'
vowels = 'aeiou'

text_dict = {}
for char in text.lower():
    if char in vowels:
        text_dict[char] = text_dict.get(char, 0) + 1

min_count = min(text_dict.values())
minimum_dict = {k: v for k, v in text_dict.items() if v == min_count}

print(minimum_dict) # {'e': 1, 'o': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
frequent_vowels = {k:v for k,v in vowels.items() if v != 0}
print(frequent_vowels)
```